# Problem reading text files without extensions in python

Tags: python, file

I have written a piece of a code which is supposed to read the texts inside several files which are located in a directory. These files are basically text files but they do not have any extensions.But my code is not able to read them:

```
corpus_path = 'Reviews/'

for infile in glob.glob(os.path.join(corpus_path,'*.*')):
    review_file = open(infile,'r').read()
    print review_file
```

To test if this code works, I put a dummy text file, dummy.txt. which worked because it has extension. But i don't know what should be done so files without the extensions could be read.
can someone help me? Thanks

Comment: What output do you get when you run the script?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `*` instead of `*.*`.

The latter requires an extension to be present (more precisely, there needs to be a dot in the filename), the former doesn't.

Answer (score 6):

Glob patterns don't work the same way as wildcards on the Windows platform. Just use `*` instead of `*.*`. i.e. `os.path.join(corpus_path,'*')`. Note that `*` will match *every* file in the directory - if that's not what you want then you can revise the pattern accordingly.

See the [glob module documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/glob.html) for more details.

Comment: How do wildcards on Windows work - there's always some extension?

Comment: On Windows, `*.*` will match any file even if it has no extension so a pattern like `file*.*` would match `file1.txt` and `filewithnoextension`. The glob pattern `*.*` means zero or more characters followed by a literal `.` followed by zero or more characters so if you have a filename without a `.` it won't match.

Answer (score 3):

You could search for `*` instead of `*.*`, but this will match *every* file in your directory.

Fundamentally, this means that you will have to handle cases where the file you are opening is not a text file.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that you need

```
from os import listdir

from filename in ( fn for fn in listdir(corpus_path) if '.' not in fn):
    # do something
```

you could write

```
from os import listdir

for fn in listdir(corpus_path):
    if '.' not in fn:
        # do something
```

but the former with a generator spares one indentation level

Comment: This still does not enable you to open the file. `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:`